# Calling median() on Pandas Dataframe column resulting in 0 after replacing np.nan

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, median

I made this function to call on a column and replace nans with 0, then convert the column (float type) to int:

```
def convert_to_int(df, col):
    df[col] = df[col].replace(np.nan, 0)
    df[col] = df[col].astype(int)
```

I am able to successfully call the function on my data frame column, and the data type returns as int like I want to. However if I try to call .median() like so:

```
df['column_name'].median()
```

It returns 0. Am I doing something wrong?

**UPDATE**

After running value_counts(), it appears that I have around 4000 0's in that column. Could it really make the median 0 then?

**Second Update**
For anyone ever in the same situation as mine, running .quantile() on that column could be helpful. I was able to confirm the median truly is 0 by printing this quantile table out for myself:

```
df['column_name'].quantile([.0, 0.001, 0.25, .5, 0.75, 0.999, 1])
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in your function `convert_to_int(df, col)` it convert all the nan to zero so it affects the  median simply.

Comment: Instructions were to fill nan with 0, and then fill the 0's with the median of the new int column. As long as I am not messing with the other numbers I think I am on the right track and was just overthinking the median being 0.

Comment: @andreaq exactly  the median is zero and no problem in that as my answer suggent ^^

Comment: @andreaq you can  also use `df[col] = df[col].fillna(0).astype(int)` instead of `replace()` as it is faster ^^